# How to keep both behavior "single sign on" and "session time out"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, openid

I have implemented "single sign on" on my site. That means if user login on site A, user can visit my site.

But It cause the "session time out" behavior breaked. If user login to my site, and then when the seesion times out, firstly the "single sign on" is checked. It found user already login with openid, and then auto sign in for the user.

How can I keep both behavior "single sign on" and "session time out"?

Comment: Redirect to a different page (not login page) upon session timeout?

Comment: But once user try to access the login page, we will do single sign on for the user.

Comment: That's the way it supposed to be isn't it? Login page should not distinguish whether it's a new user logging in or a user whose session just expired. This is why you should have a "session expired" page separate from "login" page and user whose session expired should be able to logn again - but by explicitly going to login page

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this; OpenId does not implement a "single sign out" mechanism, so the best you could do is mark your local application session as logged out.

Comment: Yes. That's the question. How to mark our local application session as logged out? I tried to redirect to login page. But the login page will do "single sign on", and then I get into the system.

Comment: @caesarliu I think how your application keeps track of sign-in state is specific to your application.  I image you track the current session and if its authenticated.  If so, just abandon the current session and start with a new unauthenticated one.